# OneDrive constantly comes back in Windows 10, despite being disabled in every way I know how

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

What is the way of getting this thing to stop coming back up and telling me I'm over my storage limit? It seems like it's prompted to start when you go into the Documents folder of Windows Explorer. I disabled the service and the launch at startup. What else? I'm in Windows 10 Creator.

Comment: Have you actually uninstalled OneDrive? Its an app you can simply uninstall. Should stay away after that.

Comment: Me2 i just uninstalled, never seen again. Settings -> Apps -> First tab, find OneDrive right click and remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply uninstall OneDrive from the Control Panel -> Programs and Features.

Alternatively, rightclick the start button -> Apps and Features, then find Microsoft OneDrive, click it, press Uninstall, and *poof* problems vanish while it uninstalls.

Comment: Alt alt -> press windows key + x -> Programs and Features.